# convert postgres dump insert to batch transaction?

Tags: postgresql

I am searching for a tool/script to convert a postgresql dump file of gigabytes size to a batch transaction commit file.

it should insert `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` of transactions in the dump file like so:

```
BEGIN;
CREATE...;
INSERT...;
INSERT...;
INSERT...;
...
COMMIT; 
BEGIN;
CREATE...;
INSERT...;
INSERT...;
INSERT...;
....
```

Yes. Anything would be better than insert statements. The problem is that the data consists of gigabytes of insert statements and the delivering partner is not reachable to send another dump format.

Do you know a tool to convert/accelerate the import?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because i couldn't find a tool i created my own script to do the job:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
i=0
File.open(ARGV[1],"a"){|t|
    File.open(ARGV[0]){|f|                                                                                        
    a=[]
    while(l=f.gets(";"))                                                                               
      if(a.length==80)
          i+=1
          puts "i: #{i}" if(i%1000==0)
          t.write("BEGIN;\n#{a.join(" ")}\nCOMMIT;\n")
          a=[]
      else
        a<<l
      end
    end
    t.write("BEGIN;\n#{a.join(" ")}\nCOMMIT;\n")
      }
  }
```

Usage: `ruby batchtransact.rb input.sql output.sql`

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using the [`COPY` command](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-copy.html), the [`\copy` meta-command of `psql`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS), or the [`pg_bulkload` utility](http://pgbulkload.projects.postgresql.org/).  Any of these should be significantly faster than the Ruby script you show, and have been well-tested for correct handling of line breaks and other odd characters within the data.

Comment: Yes anything would be better. The problem was that the data consists of gigabytes of insert statements and the delivering partner is not reachable to send another dump format. So i tried to find another solution.

Comment: Ah, it's unfortunate that you couldn't get the data in some more tabular format. Just be cautious about data that might fool your parsing. I think your bottleneck is going to be the parsing of the INSERT statements to pick out values, so besides grouping multiple statements into a single transaction (as you have done), I don't think there's much you can do to speed it up.